# Jmeter Assertion fails even when Response Status Code is 200

Tags: jmeter

My Jmeter assertion fails even when the response status code is properly returned as 200. Gets the message as
****** received  : 200[[[ ]]]

****** comparison: 200[[[

]]]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this empty pattern:

[image]

Remove it so your [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) would look like:

[image]

and it should resolve your issue. Also double check that your `200` pattern doesn't contain line breaks

- correct:

  [image]
- incorrect

  [image]

mind the cursor position

More information: [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-three-easy-steps)